# What are the differences between Mythbuntu and MythTV?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I've heard about both, however I've never been able to distinguish how they are distinct, [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) as I see it is used as a Desktop environment, whereas [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) seems to be installed on a TV itself with an equivalent App on the Mythbuntu desktop. I may be entirely wrong in making this assumption though.

I've also heard of Mythbuntu being used as a "*frontend* " with MythTV as a "*backend* " if someone could clarify this concept I'd be quite grateful as for me I thought MythTV also qualified as a "*frontend*".

In short:

- How are Mythbuntu and MythTV related and what are their major differences?
- What are the definitions of a frontend and backend in the case of Mythbuntu and MythTV?
- Is Mythbuntu required for MythTV to work?

I've already read the following questions but I've got very basic knowledge on this issue and none really explain things in an Average Joe-*esque* way for users with little knowledge on the subject.

- [How do I connect a MythTV frontend to a MythTV backend on Mythbuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97335/how-do-i-connect-a-mythtv-frontend-to-a-mythtv-backend-on-mythbuntu-11-10)
- [How do I Install MythTV on a Lenovo S12 with wireless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81186/how-do-i-install-mythtv-on-a-lenovo-s12-with-wireless)
- [Mythmote wont connect to mythbuntu 12.04, seems frontend is not listening on all interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127445/mythmote-wont-connect-to-mythbuntu-12-04-seems-frontend-is-not-listening-on-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How are Mythbuntu and MythTV related and what are their major differences?

- Mythbuntu is the official operating system based on Ubuntu.
- [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) is software that acts like a PVR (personal video recording) system. It is not limited to Ubuntu but can be used on Fedora called MythDora.

> What are the definitions of a frontend and backend in the case of Mythbuntu and MythTV?

- The front end is the software required for the visual elements (GUI) and is used to find, play, and manipulate media files. The back end is the server where the media files, tuners, and database are actually stored.

> Is Mythbuntu required for MythTV to work?

- No. You can also use other Linux based systems like Fedora and also Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added another sub-question above, also regarding the PVR system, does this mean using MythTV you could record anything being broadcast on your TV as long as MythTV can connect to the TV via wireless/wired connection?

Comment: It's worth noting that Mythdora no longer exists/has stopped development. Mythbuntu and LinHES (Arch) are the two that are left.